# Using a third party library that requires a minimum sdk

Tags: android

is it possible to use a library that requires a minimum sdk of for example , 21 , in my project which has min sdk of 8? I was thinking of checking device api at runtime. If its above 21, use that libraries tools. Is this logical ? Or will gradle not even let me compile the library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably doable by branch checking SDK version in code level like if android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11 then do not run this, but not recommended by [dev guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#considerations):

Platform version must be lower than or equal to the Android project

A library is compiled as part of the dependent application project, so the API used in the library project must be compatible with the version of the Android library used to compile the application project. In general, the library project should use an API level that is the same as — or lower than — that used by the application. If the library project uses an API level that is higher than that of the application, the application project will not compile. It is perfectly acceptable to have a library that uses the Android 1.5 API (API level 3) and that is used in an Android 1.6 (API level 4) or Android 2.1 (API level 7) project, for instance.

[Original Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9658554/5545429)